# Form does not submit in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to submit a form in laravel 5 but it does not call the update function.

```
<form class="form-horizontal", role="form" method="patch"      action{{url('/user/'.$user->id) }}">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $user-  >name }}">
    </div>
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Please, fix typos in the title of question

Answer (score 2):

The `action` attribute is not complete, should be `action="..."`

You can also use route instead of url e.g.

In blade:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal", role="form" method="patch" action="{{ route('user.show') }}">
```

In routes.php:

```
    Route::get('user/{id}', [
       'uses' => 'UsersController@action',
       'as' => 'user.show'
    ]);
```

Comment: i am not use show function, i user edit.blade.php for html form and then i am sending this form to update function which is in UserController as  public function update($id)
   {   
   $user = User::find($id);
  $user->name = Request::input('name');
  $user->email = Request::input('email');
  $user->mobile = Request::input('mobile');
  $user->save();
   return view('user/index');
 }

Answer (score 0):

The action is incorrect. Missing = and beginning ". You also have a , after class. Not valid html.

If you want to pass parameters to an URL then maybe you should consider this.

```
url('foo/bar', $parameters = [], $secure = null);
```

Comment: i am not use show function, i user edit.blade.php for html form and then i am sending this form to update function which is in UserController as public function update($id) { $user = User::find($id); $user->name = Request::input('name'); $user->email = Request::input('email'); $user->mobile = Request::input('mobile'); $user->save(); return view('user/index'); }

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid, you are missing the `action` attribute. HTML forms should generally take the form:

```
<form action="where/form/submits/to" method="form-method"> ... </form>
```

see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) for details on the form element.
In your case that will is should be like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal", role="form" method="patch" action="{{url('/user/'.$user->id) }}"> ... </form>
```

Comment: i am using action="{{ route(url('/user/'.$user->id) }}" but not working.

Comment: Your form is also missing a submit button.